# What should I call this unique-pointer-with-size structure?

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation, terminology, unique-ptr, naming, std-span

I'm annoyed by how C++' standard library only offers some functionality via pointers rather than structures which keep both an address and a size. Specifically, suppose I want something like a `unique_ptr<T[]>`, but which keeps the associated length/size.

This is not that hard to implement (especially if I avoid the need to distinguish between array and non-array template parameters like in `make_unique()`); but - what should I call this unique-ptr-with-size ? I was thinking of `unique_span` or `unique_region`... or maybe there is some other name that's more appropriate, or more popular, for this structure?

<sub>Note: It doesn't seem to be any of the vector-like constructs listed in [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67409337/1593077).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no `std` or `boost` container that quite fits this purpose.

I recommend calling it `unique_span`, as it is practically a `std::span`, with the added property of owning the data.